# ng-if expression not evaluating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am a very confused as to why my ng-if expression is not evaluating like I think it should be. I am taking the ID of the button from the previous page, and trying to match that ID with a new ID on the next page with an ng-if expression.

My index.html page produces the amount of buttons based off my JSON object data, then when one gets clicked, it should go in my getButtonClicked scope with the correct ID of the button clicked. In the scope, I store this correct ID in a sessionStorage.

index.html

```
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <button ng-repeat="x in data" id="{{x.id}}" ng-click="getButtonClicked(x.id)"  onclick="window.location='secondPage.html';" >{{x.id}} {{x.userFirstName}} {{x.userLastName}}</button>
    </div>
```

retrieveData.js

```
// creates a module
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);


myApp.controller('AppCtrl' , function($scope, $http){

        $http.get("thisurlworksjustreplacingip")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.data = response;});

        $scope.getButtonClicked = function(buttonNumber){
            sessionStorage.setItem("school", buttonNumber);
        }
});

function returnSchool(){
    return (sessionStorage.getItem("school"));
}
```

Then on my secondPage.html I try to match up the sessionStorage variable, which I return in returnSchool() to the ID of a button in ng-if. So if you clicked the second button on the first page, it should show a button on the second page with that same data. Eventually I will change the data that is displayed on the button, I just want get the ID's matched properly before I do so.

secondPage.html

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="x in data" id="{{x.id}}" ng-if="x.id == returnSchool()">X ID: {{x.id}} Get Value: {{returnSchool()}} {{x.userFirstName}} {{x.userLastName}}</button>
</div>
<script>console.log(returnSchool());</script>
```

The thing I do not understand is, when I try to print it out on the button using angular, returnSchool() will not print anything. When I print out returnSchool() in the console below, it prints out the correct ID of the button I clicked on the last page (1,2,3,4). If I change ng-if="x.id == returnSchool()", which displays no buttons, to ng-if="x.id != returnSchool()", it prints all the buttons, leaving me to believe that maybe returnSchool() does not equal the button id pressed on the previous page? I think something is just not evaluating properly in my ng-if.

Comment: returnSchool should be defined with $rootScope.returnSchool

Comment: Look like returnSchool function is not in controller scope so it can't evaluate in ng-if

Comment: That was the problem... feel like an idiot, but thank you very much!